# Is there any way to have a default integer passed inside a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

For my homework assignment, the stored procedure should accept an optional integer between 1 and 15, but default to 3 if no value is passed.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE rankVideos(rank INT)
BEGIN
    if rank = null then
        SET rank = 3;
    END if;
    
 CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE all_ranks AS (
 SELECT * FROM youtube.homework7a
 );

 create OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 AS ( SELECT
 category,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) v_cnt, 
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY views DESC) v_views,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY likes DESC) v_likes,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dislikes DESC) v_dislikes,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY comment_count DESC) v_comment_count FROM all_ranks
 );


 CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE t3 AS (
 SELECT * FROM t2
 WHERE v_cnt <= rank OR v_views <= rank OR v_likes <= rank
 OR v_dislikes < rank OR v_comment_count <= rank
 );


 CREATE OR replace TEMPORARY TABLE t4 AS (
 SELECT category,
 case when v_cnt <= rank then v_cnt ELSE null END cnt,
 case when v_views <= rank then v_views ELSE null END views,
 case when v_likes <= rank then v_likes ELSE null END likes,
 case when v_dislikes <= rank then v_dislikes ELSE null END dislikes,
 case when v_comment_count <= rank then v_comment_count ELSE null END comment_count
 FROM t3
 )
;

SELECT *,
ifnull(cnt,999)
 + ifnull(views,999) 
 + ifnull(likes,999) 
 + ifnull(dislikes,999) 
 +ifnull(comment_count,999) num_non_null_cols,
ifnull(cnt,0)
 + ifnull(views,0)
 + ifnull(likes,0)
 + ifnull(dislikes,0)
 + ifnull(comment_count,0) sum_non_null_cols
FROM t4
ORDER BY num_non_null_cols, sum_non_null_cols;


END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

When I run the procedure and leave the integer blank I get an error that it has an incorrect integer value.

Comment: What type of SQL? MS SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: `if rank = null` should be `if rank is null`.

Comment: That narrows it down to MariaDB, MySQL, MS SQL, PostgreSQL and SQLLite. Please work out which one and tag accordingly. They all have different syntax for default parameters.

Comment: Gotcha I believe I'm using MariaDB.

Comment: @camjace321 For future reference, you should usually use the `mysql` tag for MariaDB, it's a fork of the public MySQL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you show makes me think you are using MySQL or MariaDB.

These implementations don't support a feature for default values for procedure parameters. This has been requested in MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15975 But so far, it is not supported.

You're using the best workaround I know of, to set the parameter to your default value if it is NULL.

Another way of coding this is to use the [COALESCE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function:

```
SET rank = COALESCE(rank, 3);
```

It's just another way to achieve the same thing that your IF/THEN code does.

Answer (score 0):

SQL
MSSQL

create proc MyProc
@rank int = 3
as
...
GO

If you pass in a value, it will use that value. If you don't pass in a value, @rank = 3.